# Spring method to get all beans of a given type

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to get all the beans of the same type from an `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext`.

I was using `factory.getBeansOfType(SomeType.class)` but I have noticed it only returns top-level beans, is there any other method I can use that would return all the beans of a given type, even nested beans?

Example usage:

```
<bean name="topLevelBean" class="SomeClass">
    <property name="someProperty">
         <bean bean="nestedBean" class="SomeClass">
    </property>
</bean>
```

Calling `factory.getBeansOfType(SomeClass.class)` returns only `topLevelBean` but not `nestedBean`.

Documentation of `getBeansOfType` says it only returns top-level beans.

My question is: is there any method that returns all beans of the desired type.

Comment: what do you mean by top level beans?

Comment: This is the first time I hear about nested beans.

Comment: Please add your `context.xml` and the Java code you use.

Comment: Add some relevent code.

Comment: I added an example of what I mean by top level and nested bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get access to all the beans by implementing the [BeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) interface and adding it to the spring context file.

Comment: Is there any annotation to add at the class level instead of implementing BeanPostProcessor?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but possibly [BeanFactoryUtils#beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactoryUtils.html#beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors%28org.springframework.beans.factory.ListableBeanFactory,%20java.lang.Class%29) might return those (doc doesn't say).

Comment: I tried it, it returns the same list as factory.getBeansOfType (I don't have any parent context).

Comment: @Marcel Is there any annotation which I can add at class level instead of using BeanFactoryUtils?